# Merge a string to a line extracted from a text file in UNIX

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I wanted to merge a string `ABC` to a line that I have extracted from a file.

The following command is used to extract the lines 20-25 in `file_ABC`, take only the first column, which is then transposed to become a row (or line).

```
sed -n '20,25p' < file_ABC | awk '{print $1}' | paste -s
```

This is the result:

```
2727778 14734   0   0   0   2713044
```

I would like to add at the first position of this line the string `ABC`.

```
ABC 2727778 14734   0   0   0   2713044
```

Any suggestion on how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick hack would be to use something like

```
printf 'ABC\t%s\n' "$(sed -n '20,25p' < file_ABC | awk '{print $1}' | paste -s)"
```

You could modify your initial command instead to use awk for everything, though:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {printf "ABC"}
    NR>=20 && NR<=25 {printf "\t%s", $1}
    END {print ""}
' file_ABC
```

Comment: I prefer the `awk` above the given hack or using `| sed 's/^/ABC\t/'`.

Comment: @WalterA Yeah, the hack was mostly "what's the smallest change in OP's code to get what they want", and awk how I'd do it from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '20,25{s/\s.*//;H};$!d;x;s/^/ABC/;s/\n/ /g' file
```

Gather up the first column fields by appending them to the hold space for rows 20 to 25 only. At the end of the file prepend `ABC` and replace the introduced newlines by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep all in one script

```
$ awk 'BEGIN            {line="ABC"} 
       NR>=20 && NR<=25 {line=line FS $1} 
       NR==25           {print line; exit}' file
```

improved version as suggested by @EdMorton

```
$awk 'NR>=20 {line=line OFS $1} 
      NR==25 {print "ABC" line; exit}' file
```

Comment: @EdMorton thx.  Of course that's much better.  I blame it on the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

For fun, bash only

```
filename=file_ABC
words=("${filename##*_}")
i=0
while read -r word rest_of_line; do 
    ((++i < 20 )) && continue
    ((  i > 25 )) && break
    words+=("$word")
done < "$filename"
join() { local IFS=$1; shift; echo "$*"; }
join $'\t' "${words[@]}"
```

But this will be much slower than a single awk call.